# Products appearing in wrong category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce store, I have a number of products which are showing under the incorrect category both on the store frontend and in the backend when browsing products under that category.

The category is ID 164

The products are not assigned to this category. Furthermore, I have checked the term_relationships table and bizarrely the product IDs which are shown in the wrong category do not even have a relationship with it. (see image below)

The product IDs which are showing in this category but are not assigned to it are: 399, 383, 383, 142 (see image below)

[image]

I have changed the theme of my store to WordPress Twenty Twenty to rule out any theme issues and the issue still persists.

This is an issue across my entire site and this is just a small example under a single category.

A lot of these products were created using Yoast Duplicate Post. I am wondering if this has caused these products to end up in the category of the originating product? Still, it is strange how there is no relationship?

Has anyone had any experience of this? Other than the term_relationship table is there anything else which determines what category a product belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this answer would be helpful to others as I can't be the only one to have experienced this issue.

If we look at a problem category, several unrelated categories are included in the query.

It should be 33,34,79,80,88,99,168 which are the sub-categories plus the main category ID.

Instead we see a query for 15,35,43,168.

Interestingly, when I switch the category to be a child category, the list is correct.

I also found that once I switched it back to be a parent category, it was still right. When I checked the other categories they appeared to be correct now too.

**What to Do?**

Try temporarily making one of the categories a sub-category. You can do that by going to Products > Categories and clicking on one of the top-level categories. In the "parent category" drop-down, select another top-level category and then save your changes. Then change the "parent category" back to "none" and save it again.

**What Happened?**

I suspect there was some *caching in the database* which was causing incorrect sub-categories to be included in category archives.

Also, I would suggest reaching out to the web host and see what *database caching* is in place. They may have a way for you to clear the cache if you run into issues like this.